# Asp.net core file uploads reporting progress back to the front end

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am currently uploading files using an form post method I see many examples but not for IFromFile usuage I was wondering how one would report progress. Im using asp.net core 3.1

I am posting my files using an a multipart form to post the files.

```
<form  method="post" asp-controller="FileAttachments"  asp-action="UploadFiles" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <input type="file" id="FormFile" multiple="multiple" class="btn-primary float-left" name="FormFile">
    <input type="submit" id="btnUpload" class="btn-primary float-right"    value="Upload Files" />
 </div>
```

And here is my controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> FormFile) {


    Int32.TryParse(TempData.Peek("CaseId").ToString(), out int resultCaseId);

    long size = FormFile.Sum(f => f.Length);
    FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.None;
    foreach (var fileAttachments in FormFile) {
    if (fileAttachments.Length > 0) {

    string filePath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Uploads");
    var tennantId = GetCurrentTennantId().Result;
    var settings = _context.SystemSetup.FirstOrDefault().UploadFolderPath;

    string uniqueFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + fileAttachments.FileName;
    string savedFileName = Path.Combine(filePath, uniqueFilename);



    await fileAttachments.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(savedFileName, FileMode.Create));
    FileInfo infoFile = new FileInfo(savedFileName);
    string extension = infoFile.Extension.Replace(".", "");
    var caseOfficer = _context.Users.Where(w => w.Id == tennantId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();


    if (Constants.imageExtensions.Contains(extension)) {
        fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Image;
    } else if (extension.Contains("pdf")) {
        fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.PDF;
    } else if (Constants.videoFormats.Contains(extension)) {
        fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Video;
    } else if (Constants.excelExtensions.Contains(extension)) {
        fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Excel;
    } else if (Constants.wordExtensions.Contains(extension)) {
        fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Word;
    } else if (Constants.audioExtensions.Contains(extension)) {
        fileAttachmentType = FileAttachments.FileAttachmentTypes.Voice;
    }

    var test = fileAttachmentType;
    FileAttachments attachments = new FileAttachments {
        DocumentPath = filePath,
        CaseId = resultCaseId,
        FullPath = savedFileName,
        FileSize = infoFile.Length,
        OrignalFileName = fileAttachments.FileName,
        FileAttachmentType = fileAttachmentType,
        TennantId = await GetCurrentTennantId(),
        Extension = infoFile.Extension.Replace(".", "").ToLower(),
        UploadedBy = caseOfficer.Id,
        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
        File = uniqueFilename,
        ContentType = fileAttachments.ContentType,
        isActive = true,
        isDeleted = false
    };

    _context.Add(attachments);

             
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    MISAuditTrail _auditrail = new MISAuditTrail();
    _auditrail.MISObjectId = resultCaseId;
    _auditrail.TennantId = tennantId;
    _auditrail.CreatedBy = caseOfficer.FirstName;
    _auditrail.IPAddressBytes = this.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

    _auditrail.AuditType = (int)fileAttachmentType;
    _auditrail.Action = "File was Uploaded " + attachments.FileAttachmentType.GetDisplayName() + "Filename : "+ attachments.OrignalFileName.ToString();
    _auditrail.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    _auditrail.isActive = true;
    _auditrail.isDeleted = false;

    _context.Add(_auditrail);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    }

  _toast.AddInfoToastMessage("Files has been upload sucesfully");
          
  return RedirectToAction("Edit", "MISObjects", new { id = resultCaseId });

 }
}
```

I would like to acheive something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This medium article](https://medium.com/@dmitrysikorsky/file-uploading-with-a-progress-bar-in-asp-net-core-771c9580795f) by [Dmirty Sikorsky](https://medium.com/@dmitrysikorsky) seems to be this what you are looking for.
The source code with the demo project is available on [GitHub repo](https://github.com/DmitrySikorsky/AspNetCoreUploadingProgress).

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(IList<IFormFile> files)
{
  Startup.Progress = 0;

  long totalBytes = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

  foreach (IFormFile source in files)
  {
    string filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(source.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

    filename = this.EnsureCorrectFilename(filename);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

    using (FileStream output = System.IO.File.Create(this.GetPathAndFilename(filename)))
    {
      using (Stream input = source.OpenReadStream())
      {
        long totalReadBytes = 0;
        int readBytes;

        while ((readBytes = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
          await output.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, readBytes);
          totalReadBytes += readBytes;
          Startup.Progress = (int)((float)totalReadBytes / (float)totalBytes * 100.0);
          await Task.Delay(10); // It is only to make the process slower
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return this.Content("success");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Progress()
{
  return this.Content(Startup.Progress.ToString());
}
```

From the article:

> In general, we just need to count the bytes
> number read from a request input stream, compare it with the total
> request stream length and then get this value from the client-side

Comment: That only works by making the client app continuously call the back-end, in the article every 10ms (which can certainly only work in local, 10ms is not enough for any kind of latency). This is a nice solution if you have <5 users, but it doesn't scale at all. Only way this would be efficient would be with server to client connections, like with websockets.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I haven't thought about it at all, to be honest... So instead of exposing the endpoint we could use [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for example?

Comment: Its really only for 11 users now that work in an office enviorment this might be a hosted solution and not a External one.

Comment: Exactly, something like SignalR is meant for tasks like this one. @rogue39nin for 11 users, this might be just fine, just make the UI call the endpoint every 1 second should be enough